# How to use enum to get string value

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, cell

Actually I'm trying to Populate API JSON data to tableView but I cannot use enum as a string.

```
struct Results: Codable {
    let container_id : Int?
    let container_number : String?
    let shipment_id : Int?
    let bill_of_lading : BillOfLading
    let eta : String?
    let discharge_port_id : Int?
    let discharge_port_name : String?
    let consignee_id : Int?
    let consignee_name : String?
    let customer_id : Int?
    let customer_name : String?
    let shipment_status : String?
    let container_status : String?
    let user_id : Int?
    let user_display_name : String?
    let commodities : [Commodities]
    let all_sold : Bool?
    let quantities : Quantities
    let sales : [String]?
    let sales_report : Sales_report
    let commodities_summary : String?
    let commodity_quantity_summary : String?
    let commodities_summary_en : String?
    let commodity_quantity_summary_en : String?
}

enum BillOfLading: Codable {
    case integer(Int)
    case string(String)

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if let x = try? container.decode(Int.self) {
            self = .integer(x)
            return
        }
        if let x = try? container.decode(String.self) {
            self = .string(x)
            return
        }
        throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(BillOfLading.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Wrong type for BillOfLading"))
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        switch self {
        case .integer(let x):
            try container.encode(x)
        case .string(let x):
            try container.encode(x)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: This is the error picture]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Btw, try `dataa.bill_of_lading.rawValue`

Comment: I tried this but i get  Value of type 'BillOfLading' has no member 'rowValue'

Comment: Unrelated, because this is Swift, I might suggest using camelCase for property names. And when decoding, I’d set the `keyDecodingStrategy` of the `JSONDecoder` to [`.convertFromSnakeCase`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder/keydecodingstrategy/convertfromsnakecase). Likewise, if encoding, I’d set `keyEncodingStrategy` of the `JSONEncoder` to [`.convertToSnakeCase`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonencoder/keyencodingstrategy/converttosnakecase). We shouldn’t let the key convention of our API dictate our property naming convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a computed property, e.g.

```
extension BillOfLading {
    var stringValue: String {
        switch self {
            case .integer(let value): return String(value)
            case .string(let value): return value
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can do

```
cell.bolLabel.text = data.bill_of_lading.stringValue
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `cell.bolLable.text = dataa.bill_of_lading` 
where `bill_of_lading` is of `BillOfLading` type, 
and `bolLable.text` accept string type only.

try `cell.bolLable.text = dataa.bill_of_lading.string`

Comment: when I'm trying to use cell.bolLable.text = dataa.bill_of_lading.string i get this error
Enum case 'string' cannot be used as an instance member

Answer (score -1):

Here is a workaround which is working fine for me

```
// MARK: - Imagefile
struct Imagefile : Codable
{
let large, thumb: String?
let pageName: String?
let pageKey: BookType?

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case large, thumb
    case pageName = "page_name"
    case pageKey = "page_key"
    }
}

enum BookType: Codable {
case int(Int)
case string(String)
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
    if let x = try? container.decode(Int.self) {
        self = .int(x)
        return
    }
    if let x = try? container.decode(String.self) {
        self = .string(x)
        return
    }
    throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(BookType.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Wrong type for BookType"))
}
func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
    switch self {
    case .int(let x):
        try container.encode(x)
    case .string(let x):
        try container.encode(x)
    }
}
```

}

Here I am using BookType.